# Generating diagram of Haskell data structures

Tags: haskell, graph

I am searching for a tool that, given a file with several data structures in Haskell, is able to generate a diagram with the relationships between the data structures.

I currently have a file with a parse tree (+- 600 lines) and I'd like to see the parse tree more visually. What are my options?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know anything about a Haskell-specific tool. You'll probably end up using something powered by GraphVis.

Comment: So you say you only care about `data` type declarations, not about the actual code?

Comment: @Bergi, indeed, I only want to see the data declarations.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use the [`diagrams`](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/) library, which has a variety of backends. The `diagrams-contrib` package includes auxiliary functions for [rendering trees](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-contrib-1.3.0/docs/Diagrams-TwoD-Layout-Tree.html). So perhaps you could convert your parse tree into a [rose tree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Tree.html) from `Data.Tree` and render it in this way.

The following example uses the SVG backend:

```
module Treeish where

-- This example requires the containers, 
-- diagrams-core, diagrams-lib, diagrams-contrib and diagrams-svg packages
import Data.Tree
import Diagrams.Prelude 
import Diagrams.TwoD.Layout.Tree (renderTree,symmLayout',_slHSep,_slVSep)
import Diagrams.Backend.SVG (SVG)
import Diagrams.Backend.SVG.CmdLine (defaultMain)

exampleTree :: Tree String
exampleTree = Node "A" [Node "B" [], Node "C" []]

renderNodeTree :: Tree String -> QDiagram SVG V2 Double Any
renderNodeTree nodeTree = renderTree 
    (\a -> letter a `atop` square 1.03 # fc white) 
    (~~) 
    (symmLayout' (with{ _slHSep = 3,  _slVSep = 2}) nodeTree)
  where
     letter a = text a # font "monospace" # fontSize (local 0.47) 

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain (renderNodeTree exampleTree)
```

[`renderTree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-contrib-1.3.0/docs/Diagrams-TwoD-Layout-Tree.html#v:renderTree) is a function that, given a function that creates a diagram for a tree node, and a function that creates a line between two given points, returns a function that creates a diagram out of a tree that has been annotated with node positions.

The position annotations are added using the [`symmLayout'`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-contrib-1.3.0/docs/Diagrams-TwoD-Layout-Tree.html#v:symmLayout-39-) function.

[`with`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-lib-1.3/docs/Diagrams-Util.html) is just a synonym for `default` from `Data.Default`.

[`(~~)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-lib-1.2.0.8/docs/Diagrams-TrailLike.html#v:-126--126-) creates a line between two points.

When the program is run from the command line (with something like `runhaskell Treeish -o foo.svg -w 300`) it will generate a SVG file that can be viewed in the browser:

[image]

[Here](http://original.livestream.com/pivotallabs/video?clipId=pla_d5335c67-cda3-45a2-81ef-547b26ce403d) and [here](http://original.livestream.com/pivotallabs/video?clipId=pla_f55a313d-c5ed-4dbc-b5dd-71b67f30e11f) are two parts of a recent tutorial on `diagrams`.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you want to take the AST of some Haskell code and visualise that. How about first parsing it using https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src and then generating output using https://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphviz.

If it's not an AST you want to visualise, just map your data structure to GraphViz output and ignore the Parser.Haskell part.

In any case, I'd assume rolling your own visualisation code would be the most flexible way, and given Haskell's expressiveness, probably not too laborious.